# Checking if a port is currently in use (Java)

Tags: java, sockets, port

So, I've built a server manager in java to boot and close game servers on the extra box that I have lying around, but now I'm looking for a way to close down servers that aren't in use automatically.

My current thought was to check if a port was receiving any data with the server manager, and if it goes for a period without any data being caught, to close the server. That's where I run into the issue of being unable to read ports because java can't bind to a port that is already in use. Is there some way to monitor activity on a port without specifically binding to it?

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

-Mot

[EDIT]

OS: 
Windows 7 Home Premium

What I've tried thus far: 
-ServerSockets to bind to the port and listen 
-DatagramSockets to bind to the port and listen

I'm currently looking into netstat via cmd to see if I can pull any valuable details from there, but no dice thus far

Comment: Post your OS(es), and also post what you've tried.

Comment: You can use a tool like Jpcap to capture what is going on on the wire